# Bracket Equation Alignment in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I'm trying to type something in a bracket with Microsoft Word. How do I align left for each line so the alignment wouldn't be center? Thank you guys.

[image]

Comment: Did you try just selecting the text and then using either the menu or right-click options to pick left alignment?

Comment: Yes it did;t work =(

Comment: Can you describe how you are creating/formatting this (equation editor, table, text box, etc.)?

Comment: Yes. I typed S2233 then I inserted a brackets equation with 3 cases. The problem is that as my text / equation gets longer, the other text / equation will get centered. I want all of the text / equation in my cases to be aligned left so it will look better. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure whether this is really a proper solution, but typing an ampersand (&) before each case worked for me.

*Update:* The & doesn't actually show up in the equation (at least in **Professional** view); it's just used as a formatting mark of some sort. The bottom part of the following image shows the same equation in **Linear** view.

[image: Left-aligned cases]

Comment: That's likely because Microsoft copied a lot of LaTeX mechanism for the Equation Editor. In LaTeX the ampersand is the aligment characater, though the `@`, used by Eq. editor as the end-of-line character is not the same for LaTeX...

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the equation column
2. `Column Alignment` -> `Left`

[image]